# Get Requested URL after Root "/" using PHP

Tags: php, url

I am wondering if there is a way to get the contents of the URL after the root slash. Example: The "page" in www.url.com/page. I would like to display this to the user on the 404 page. (How it is in the Google 404 page). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`